# Datadog RUM: Is it possible to include HTTP request body in resource logging?

Tags: android, http, logging, datadog

I am working on an Android app configured with Datadog RUM. When the device makes an HTTP request during an RUM session I can see it in the Resources section in Datadog. The log contains info about the request including the url, method and query parameters, but no request body. Is it possible to include the request body in the Datadog logging?

I imagine one would normally use APM traces for this, but I'd like to know if it's possible in RUM as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it is possible to log custom resources. It can be done using RumResourceAttributesProvider:

```
OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(new DatadogInterceptor((request, span, response, throwable) -> {},
                    new RumResourceAttributesProvider() {
                        @NonNull
                        @Override
                        public Map<String, Object> onProvideAttributes(@NonNull Request request, @Nullable Response response, @Nullable Throwable throwable) {
                            HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                            String body = null;
                            if(request.body() != null) {
                                try {
                                    final Buffer buffer = new Buffer();
                                    request.body().writeTo(buffer);
                                    body = buffer.readUtf8();
                                }
                                catch (final IOException e) {
                                    body = null;
                                }
                            }
                            if(body != null) {
                                map.put("request_body", body);
                            }
                            return map;
                        }
                    }
            ));
```

Comment: Indeed that would be the way to do it. That being said, duplicating the request_body  is something you should do with extra caution. First of all it will increase the network load for the end user, and might also impact their data plan. Secondly, doing so might bring the resource event above the size limit, and it can get rejected by the Datadog backend. Last and not least, it might also leak some PII which is something you might want to avoid.